# API unable to query Custom Object inspite of required permission

Tags: soql, soap-api, integration

We have an API integration which uses the [Salesforce cpan module](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/WWW-Salesforce-0.23/lib/WWW/Salesforce/Simple.pm) to query data from Salesforce. This module uses the API version 23.0. It works fine when it queries on objects like Account, Contract and Asset. We recently created a new object called ContractAsset which is a junction object between Contract and Asset. The API Profile for this user has Read, Edit and Create permission for this object. The query for this object doesn't work and throws the following error:

> INVALID_TYPE: sObject type \'ContractAsset__c\' is not supported.

Below is the query:

> SELECT zAsset__c, zContract__r.Support_Code__c FROM ContractAsset__c WHERE zAsset__r.SerialNumber = 'ABCD'

What might be the reason for this? Any suggestions? Below are some connection parameters been used.

```
$SF_PROXY       = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/8.0';
$SF_URI         = 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com';
$SF_PREFIX      = 'sforce';
$SF_SOBJECT_URI = 'urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com';
$SF_URIM        = 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata';
$SF_APIVERSION  = '23.0';
```

**Edit**

Here are few more details on what we have tried:

- I am able to query the object via Workbench. I even tried using the API version 23 of workbench for this.
- This integration has been live for the past 2 years. It is able to query the custom object that was created before the integration started but is unable to query 2 custom objects created after the integration was live. Of course, I haven't tested every custom object but the fact that it is able to query 1 custom object and not the 2 others made me infer this fact.

Comment: Does it work for another custom object ?

Comment: try also by logging in as this user to SFDC Workbench to see if there is access

Comment: @cropredy It worked in workbench. I have added more details on the case; please check.

Comment: @Devendra It is able to query 1 custom object but not 2 others that we have tried with till now. I have made updates to the case; please check.

Comment: Can you share with us the actual query? Strange that you're getting escaped quotes in the object name.

Comment: I have updated the post with the query used.

Comment: What does the `get_tables( )` function return?  Is ContractAsset__c included in that?

Comment: @NickCook Interesting that you ask about get_tables(). It is actually returning nothing. Not sure why. We atleast expected to receive standard objects.

Comment: Probably won't fix anything but you should bump `$SF_APIVERSION` to `37.0`.

Comment: Any reason in particular you're using API version 8 on the SOAP url? Does it make a difference if you update that to 23 or later? `https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0`

Comment: custom objects will be hidden from older API versions if they use [or have a field that uses] newer features. Try and use a newer API version and/or review what field types are in use on your custom objects.

Comment: getTables() probably isn't working because it was written against a very old API version, and the output from describeGlobal changed significantly somewhere around v16

Comment: Have you tried @MarkPond 's suggestion? If the tool you are using takes the serverUrl from the login response, you might actually be using API version 8.

Comment: Regarding get_tables(), it was an issue on our side and we are getting all the object names in get_tables() EXCEPT for this object :(

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't even know there *was* an API Version 8.0. @MarkPond

Answer (score 6):

Have you recently [registered a namespace prefix](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=register_namespace_prefix.htm) in the Org your are running the SOQL query against? If so, you will need to add the prefix to all custom object and field names.

E.g.

> SELECT abc__zAsset__c, abc__zContract__r.abc__Support_Code__c
>       FROM abc__ContractAsset__c
>      WHERE abc__zAsset__r.SerialNumber = 'ABCD'

---

Otherwise, from the [CPAN project page](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/WWW-Salesforce-0.23/lib/WWW/Salesforce/Simple.pm) you linked to I found my way over to a Github repo [p5-salesforce/WWW-Salesforce](https://github.com/p5-salesforce/WWW-Salesforce/tree/df6377d6ccffeb3b6d465930e8d0a845bcda3b99). It's been many years since I've attempted anything with Perl.

I did find [Constants.pm](https://github.com/p5-salesforce/WWW-Salesforce/blob/df6377d6ccffeb3b6d465930e8d0a845bcda3b99/lib/WWW/Salesforce/Constants.pm). What is really weird about that file is it has a number of custom objects and fields defined in it. E.g.

```
        'customobject1__c' => {
            'contact__c'       => 'xsd:string',
            'createdbyid'      => 'xsd:string',
            'createddate'      => 'xsd:dateTime',
            'field1__c'        => 'xsd:string',
            'lastmodifiedbyid' => 'xsd:string',
            'lastmodifieddate' => 'xsd:dateTime',
            'lead__c'          => 'xsd:string',
            'name'             => 'xsd:string',
            'ownerid'          => 'xsd:string',
            'systemmodstamp'   => 'xsd:dateTime',
        },
        'customer__c' => {
            'createdbyid'      => 'xsd:string',
            'createddate'      => 'xsd:dateTime',
            'lastmodifiedbyid' => 'xsd:string',
            'lastmodifieddate' => 'xsd:dateTime',
            'name'             => 'xsd:string',
            'ownerid'          => 'xsd:string',
            'systemmodstamp'   => 'xsd:dateTime',
        }
```

Perhaps you need to add any additional custom objects you want to use in that file?

That said, the error message you are getting back appears to be a standard Salesforce response when they API user doesn't have access to the sObject in question or it out right doesn't exist. I'd expect the full message to be more like:

```
INVALID_TYPE: 
zContract__r.Support_Code__c FROM ContractAsset__c WHERE zAsset__r.SerialNumber
                                  ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:53
sObject type 'ContractAsset__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
Full Query: SELECT zAsset__c, zContract__r.Support_Code__c FROM ContractAsset__c WHERE zAsset__r.SerialNumber = 'ABCD'
```

Double check that the API user that is making the call has access to the custom objects you are querying.

Comment: I will check on the part about Constants.pm. Regarding the API not having access to the object, I logged in as the API user in Salesforce and was able to view a record of that object. There is also no namespace that we have defined.

Comment: Can you see the raw api call that is getting made.

Comment: I am checking with my integration team on this. Will update soon.

Comment: Heres what we have found: Constants.pm doesn't list all the custom objects that get_tables() show. For e.g., we have a custom object Daily_Usage__c which is not constants.pm but the query on that works fine. ContractAsset__c is not in their but the query on it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the module uses partner wsdl to get Salesforce metadata information. 
--Edit--
Please follow [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73029/enterprise-wsdl-vs-partner-wsdl) solution

Comment: The Enterprise WSDL isn't required to get custom objects. It is strongly typed where as the Partner API is dynamic.

Comment: see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004760&language=en_US

Comment: It is able to query 1 custom object but not 2 others.